# How to configure the toolchains field in setting.json of Fleet?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, fleet, jetbrains-fleet

JetBrains Fleet has limited description for setting.json reference offered in [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/settings.html#reference), where `toolchains` field is merely described as "Enable toolchains for the folder or its subfolders".

The auto-generated setting.json is something like this:

```json
{
    "toolchains": []
}
```

I wonder the usage of `toolchains` and how to configure it, or where can I find a more detailed reference.

Comment: Which language? Some basic example for Go can be seen here (on a screenshot): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-17336 You should be able to configure the main thing in the Fleet's GUI settings. BTW, when you are editing the `settings.json` file, Fleet should offer you the code completion with available options. Does it work for you? (maybe it currently works in certain places only)

Comment: You can also check other tickets where "toolchains" is mentioned, they may contain other examples: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/FL?q=toolchains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select toolchains in the UI settings for your project. Here are some examples (language specific):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-java-in-fleet.html#configure-jdk
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-csharp.html#configure-toolchains
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-python.html#python-interpreter
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-go.html#configuring_go_sdk

Comment: My project doesn't show those toolchains, as in it is not able to detect Go, Python etc. So the only option is to edit `settings.json` which the documentations does not explain.